# kernel upgrade on very old rhel machines versions

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel

we have rhel servers with version 7.2 and kernel versions - `3.10.0-327.el7`

since we have network connectivity issues per [as described on Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4385541) case , we decided to upgrade the kernel from `3.10.0-327.el7` to `kernel-3.10.0-1127`

but on the next month we also preparing to upgrade the rhel version from 7.2 to 7.6

and rhel 7.6 include the kernel version = `3.10.0-957`

so I not sure if we have conflicts here ?

Comment: I think update from 7.2 to 7.6 will install older kernel, but your custom kernel should still be available via grub menu. You should be able to upgrade kernel in the same way, as you did it before, if the newest kernel gets deleted somehow, but I think it won't, because kernel is always installed and not upgraded as other packages are. I would recommend to test the upgrade procedure on a test machine. It can be a virtual machine.

Comment: Depending on exactly how the update from 7.2 to 7.6 is performed, it might not even install the old kernel: if the update is essentially a `yum update`, it should detect that the current kernel already satisfies the dependencies of the 7.6 patch level, as it's equal *or greater* than the 7.6 release kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RHEL/Fedora/CentOS allow to coinstall as many Linux kernel versions as you need.